# on_message() and @bot.command issue

Tags: python, discord.py

When I have `on_message()` in my code, it stops every other `@bot.command` commands from working. I've tried to `await bot.process_commands(message)`, but that doesn't work either. Here is my code that I have:

```
@bot.event
@commands.has_role("Owner")
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('/lockdown'):
        await bot.process_commands(message)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=":warning: Do you want to activate Lock Down?", description="Type 'confirm' to activate Lock Down mode", color=0xFFFF00)
        embed.add_field(name="\u200b", value="Lock Down mode is still in early development, expect some issues")
        channel = message.channel
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
        msg = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content='confirm')
        embed = discord.Embed(title=":white_check_mark: Lock Down mode successfully activated", description="To deactivate type '/lockdownstop'", color=0x00ff00)
        embed.add_field(name="\u200b", value="Lock Down mode is still in early development, expect some issues")
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
```

Comment: If you're using the `commands` extension, why are you processing commands in `on_message`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to place `await bot.process_commands(message)` outside of the `if` statement scope, `process_command` should be run regardless if the message startswith ”/lockdown”.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('/lockdown'):
       ...
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

By the way, `@commands.has_role(...)` cannot be applied to `on_message`. Although there aren't any errors (because there’s checking in place), `has_role` wouldn't actually work as you would've expected.

An alternative to the `@has_role` decorator would be:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.is_private or discord.utils.get(message.author.roles, name="Admin") is None:
        return False

    if message.content.startswith('/lockdown'):
       ...
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: It makes sense that `@commands.has_role` will not work with `on_message`, as the `on_message` event is not a command. It's an event that gets called every time a message is sent to a server.

Comment: One more thing, seeing as @commands.has_role("...") doesn't work for on_message(), do you know how I could have it role only?

Comment: @SirCinnamon you can access `message.author.roles` from the `message` object. You can then do something like `for role in message.author.roles: if role.name == 'Owner'` http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role

Comment: @SirCinnamon I'd probably iterate over the roles, save the result to a variable (something like `owner_role = True`) and then make it part if your already existing `if` condition. If you need further with code examples, make a new question or edit your existing one.

Comment: The alternative to the @has_role decorator will exit the function before any commands are processed unless the first `if` conditions are met