# How to make a discord bot respond to the user if they say a keyword in their message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I want to make a command where when I say a keyword that has been programmed, the bot can respond to that one word in the sentence like

`if message.content.upper().includes(‘keyword’)`

Comment: Is this regarding a discord bot?

Comment: Yes it regards a discord bot

Answer (score 2):

Reminder that you have to be on python3.5.

After installing discord: `pip3 install --user discord.py`, and [getting the token for your bot](https://github.com/reactiflux/discord-irc/wiki/Creating-a-discord-bot-&-getting-a-token):

```
from discord import Client

bot = Client()

# change keyword here
keyword = "RESPOND"

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
      message_text = message.content.strip().upper()
      if keyword in message_text:
            # do something here, change to whatever you want
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, "'{}' was said".format(keyword))

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

If you have a bot using [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#bot), you can initialize it like this instead:

```
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned)
```

Note you'll also have to include [`process_commands`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49839338/9348376) at the end of `on_message`.