# Is it possible to use on_message and @client.command in the same code?

Tags: events, command, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot. However some of my commands have had to be done on the outdated `on_message` event because they wont work under the commands extension. Is there any line of code i need to add to make the command extension work at the same time. What i mean is i have some `on_message` events and when i add a `@client.command` to the end of the code the `@client.command` commands wont respond.

**Here is an example code of what i am trying to achieve here.**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('ggg'):
        print('hello')
    elif message.content.startswith('hello')
        print('hello')

@client.command()
async def example():
    print('hello')
```

Obviously the code would be more developed. That was just an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does on\_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it can work. Only thing you need to know is `await client.process_commands(message)`. In [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) you can read about this issue.

Also check this: [on_message() and @bot.command issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837578/on-message-and-bot-command-issue)